# Customize clock + weather indicator in the lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, google-pixel

I have a Google Pixel 3 (Android 10).

Is there a way to customize or remove the clock + weather indicator in the lock screen? I have searched quite a bit but could not find any way to do so.

Comment: From [Nova FAQ](https://help.teslacoilapps.com/faq) How do I disable the weather option in the Google Search bar?
First, head into Nova Settings > Home screen > Search bar style and disable the "Weather" option at the bottom.

Then go to Nova Settings > Labs and deselect the "Weather in search bar" option.

Comment: But I don't see the weather option or the labs option. Reason is likely this as in FAQ-*As of January 31st, 2020, Google is planning to shutdown the weather API completely so this feature will no longer work at all nor will it be accessible in any way within Nova Launcher.* I am sure I did it this way when I was on Android 9 and after update to 10 too it works but then those options are missing now. Maybe search for weather app and disable that? See if that helps?

Comment: Another possibility is that you back up your Nova settings, uninstall Nova, search for an old (Android 9) times APK of Nova, install that, make the changes as per notes above, check if weather goes away. If it does, restore settings and upgrade to latest version!